# Docker volume mapping not working

Tags: node.js, docker, directory, volume, docker-volume

I'm working from the [Dockerizing a Node.js web app](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) example, trying to understand [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) from first principles.  I've uploaded it to [repl.it](https://repl.it/) with `server.js` renamed to `index.js` (due to a bug/feature where repl.it forces the existence of index.js), here are the links:

Project: https://repl.it/repls/BurlyAncientTrust

Live demo: https://BurlyAncientTrust--five-nine.repl.co

Download: https://repl.it/repls/BurlyAncientTrust.zip

I've also put together some core operations that derive container(s) from images in a functional/declarative manner rather than using names (surprisingly there's no central source for these):

```
# commands to start, list, login and remove containers/images associated with current directory's image
# build and run docker image (if it was removed with "docker rmi -f <image>" then this restores IMAGE in "docker ps")
(image=<image_name> && docker build -t $image . && docker run --rm -p <host_port>:<container_port> -d $image)
# list container id for image name
(image=<image_name> && docker ps -a -q --filter=ancestor=$image)
(image=<image_name> && docker ps -a | awk '{print $1,$2}' | grep -w $image | awk '{print $1}')
# run/exec bash inside container (similar to "vagrant ssh")
(image=<image_name> && docker exec -it $(docker ps -a -q -n=1 --filter=ancestor=$image) bash)
# remove containers for image name
(image=<image_name> && docker ps -a -q --filter=ancestor=$image | xargs docker rm -f)
# remove containers and specified image
(image=<image_name> && docker ps -a -q --filter=ancestor=$image | xargs docker rm -f && docker rmi $image)
```

**To build and run the example:**

Download and unzip BurlyAncientTrust.zip

```
cd <path_to>/BurlyAncientTrust
```

Then:

```
(image=node-web-app && docker build -t $image . && docker run --rm -p 49160:8080 -d $image)
```

Visit:

http://localhost:49160/

You should see:

```
Hello world
```

The problem is that I can't get the `-v` option for volume mapping (directory sync) working:

```
(image=node-web-app && docker ps -a -q --filter=ancestor=$image | xargs docker rm -f && docker rmi $image)
(image=node-web-app && docker build -t $image . && docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/app -p 49160:8080 -d $image)
```

I see:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

And `docker ps` no longer shows the container.  I'm on Mac OS X High Sierra so the `"$(pwd)"` portion may differ on other platforms.  You can just substitute that with the absolute path of your current working directory.  Here's the full output:

```
Zacks-Macbook:hello-system zackmorris$ (image=node-web-app && docker ps -a -q --filter=ancestor=$image | xargs docker rm -f && docker rmi $image)
Untagged: node-web-app:latest
Deleted: sha256:117288d6b7424798766b288518e741725f8a6cba657d51cd5f3157ff5cc9b784
Deleted: sha256:e2fb2f92c1fd4697c1d217957dc048583a14ebc4ebfc73ef36e54cddc0eefe06
Deleted: sha256:d274f86b6093a8e44afe1720040403e3fb5793f5fe6b9f0cf2c12c42ae6476aa
Deleted: sha256:9116e43368aba02f06eb1751e6912e4063326ce93ca1724fead8a8c1e1c6c56b
Deleted: sha256:902d4d1718530f6c7a50dd11331ee9ea85a04464557d699377115625da571b61
Deleted: sha256:261c92dc9ba95e2447e0250ea435717c855c6b184184fa050fc15fc78b1447f8
Deleted: sha256:559b16060e30ea3875772aae28a2c47508dfebda35529e87e7ff46f035669798
Deleted: sha256:4316607ec7e64e54ad59c3e46288a9fb03d9ec149b428a8f70862da3daeed4e5
Zacks-Macbook:hello-system zackmorris$ (image=node-web-app && docker build -t $image . && docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/app -p 49160:8080 -d $image)
Sending build context to Docker daemon  57.34kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:carbon
 ---> baf6417c4cac
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 00b2b9912592
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> f39ed074815e
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in b1d9bf79d502
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN docker_web_app@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN docker_web_app@1.0.0 No license field.

added 50 packages in 4.449s
Removing intermediate container b1d9bf79d502
 ---> cf2a5fce981c
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 46d46102772b
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in cd92fbacacf1
Removing intermediate container cd92fbacacf1
 ---> ac13f4eda9a2
Step 7/7 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> Running in b6cd6811b0ce
Removing intermediate container b6cd6811b0ce
 ---> 06f887984da8
Successfully built 06f887984da8
Successfully tagged node-web-app:latest
effc653267558c80fbcf017d4c10db3e46a7c944997c7e5a5fe5d8682c5c9dad
```

Docker file sharing:

[image]

```
$ pwd
/Users/zackmorris/Desktop/hello-system
```

I know that something as mission critical as volume mapping has to work.

**UPDATE**: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2991) for this, and it's looking like it may not be possible (it could be a bug/feature from the early history of Docker).  The [best answer so far](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2991#issuecomment-396567975) is that the Dockerfile calls `RUN npm install` before `"$(pwd)"` is mounted at `/usr/src/app` (which replaces the contents) so the `/usr/src/app/node_modules` directory gets replaced with nothing, which causes Node.js to crash because it can't find the `express` module, which causes the container to quit.

So I'm looking for an answer that works around this and makes this directory mapping possible in a general sense, without any weird gotchas like having to rearrange the contents of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I dug further into the distinction between Docker buildtime and runtime, specifically regarding Docker Compose, and stumbled onto this:

https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-compose-for-nodejs-development/

He was able to make it work by mapping `node_modules` as an additional volume in his `docker-compose.yml` (note that my path is `/usr/src/app` and his is `/usr/app/` so don't copypaste this):

```
volumes:
  - .:/usr/app/
  - /usr/app/node_modules
```

I'm thinking this works because it makes `node_modules` an overlayed volume, which preserves any files inside it rather than overwriting them.

I tried it as a raw Docker command `-v /usr/src/app/node_modules` and it worked! Here is a new standalone example that's identical to BurlyAncientTrust but has a `node_modules` directory added:

Project: https://repl.it/repls/RoundedImpishStructures

Live demo: https://RoundedImpishStructures--five-nine.repl.co

Download: https://repl.it/repls/RoundedImpishStructures.zip

**To build and run the example:**

Download and unzip RoundedImpishStructures.zip then:

```
cd <path_to>/RoundedImpishStructures
```

Remove the old container and image if you were using them:

```
(image=node-web-app && docker ps -a -q --filter=ancestor=$image | xargs docker rm -f && docker rmi $image)
```

Run the new example:

```
(image=node-web-app && docker build -t $image . && docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/app -v /usr/src/app/node_modules -p 49160:8080 -d $image)
```

You should see:

```
Hello world
```

Please don't upvote this answer, as I don't believe it to be a general solution.  Hopefully it helps someone though.